# Scaling Dynos with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting, scalability

I've currently got a ruby on rails app hosted on Heroku that I'm monitoring with New Relic. My app is somewhat laggy when using it, and my New Relic monitor shows me the following:

[image: NewRelicGraph]

Given that majority of the time is spent in Request Queuing, does this mean my app would scale better if I used an extra worker dynos? Or is this something that I can fix by optimizing my code? Sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm a complete newbie, and appreciate all the help. Thanks!

== EDIT ==

Just wanted to make sure I was crystal clear on this before having to shell out additional moolah. So New Relic also gave me the following statistics on the browser side as you can see here:

[image: NewRelicBrowserGraph]

This graph shows that majority of the time spent by the user is in waiting for the web application. Can I attribute this to the fact that my app is spending majority of its time in a requesting queue? In other words that the 1.3 second response time that the end user is experiencing is currently something that code optimization alone will do little to cut down? (Basically I'm asking if I have to spend money or not) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Request Queueing* basically means 'waiting for a web instance to be available to process a request'.

So the easiest and fastest way to gain some speed in response time would be to increase the number of web instances to allow your app to process more requests faster.

It might be posible to optimize your code to speed up each individual request to the point where your application can process more requests per minute -- which would pull requests off the queue faster and reduce the overall request queueing problem.

In time, it would still be a good idea to do everything you can to optimize the code anyway.  But to begin with, add more workers and your request queueing issue will more than likely be reduced or disappear.

**edit**

with your additional information, in general I believe the story is still the same -- though nice work in getting to a deep understanding prior to spending the money.

1. When you have request queuing it's because requests are waiting for *web instances* to become available to service their request. Adding more web instances directly impacts this by making more instances available.
2. It's possible that you could optimize the app so well that you significantly reduce the time to process each request. If this happened, then it would reduce request queueing as well by making requests wait a shorter period of time to be serviced.

I'd recommend giving users more *web instances* for now to immediately address the queueing problem, then working on optimizing the code as much as you can (assuming it's your biggest priority). And regardless of how fast you get your app to respond, if your users grow you'll need to implement more web instances to keep up -- which by the way is a good problem since your users are growing too.

Best of luck!

Comment: Just to be sure I get you, your answer is "yes add another worker dynos"?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to throw this in, even though this particular question seems answered. I found this blog post from New Relic and the guys over at Engine Yard: [Blog Post](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/01/22/understanding-new-relic-queuing/).

The **tl;dr** here is that Request Queuing in New Relic is not *necessarily* requests actually lining up in the queue and not being able to get processed. Due to how New Relic calculates this metric, it essentially reads a time stamp set in a header by nginx and subtracts it from `Time.now` when the New Relic method gets a hold of it. However, New Relic gets run *after* any of your code's `before_filter` hooks get called. So, if you have a bunch of computationally intensive or database intensive code being run in these `before_filter`s, it's possible that what you're seeing is actually request latency, not queuing.

You can actually examine the queue to see what's in there. If you're using Passenger, this is really easy -- just type `passenger status` on the command line. This will show you a ton of information about each of your Passenger workers, including how many requests are sitting in the queue. If you run with preceded with `watch`, the command will execute every 2 seconds so you can see how the queue changes over time (so just execute `watch passenger status`).

For Unicorn servers, it's a little bit more difficult, but there's a ruby script you can run, available [here](https://github.com/jaustinhughey/unicorn-status). This script actually examines how many requests are sitting in the unicorn socket, waiting to be picked up by workers. Because it's examining the socket itself, you shouldn't run this command any more frequently than ~3 seconds or so. The example on GitHub uses 10.

If you see a high number of queued requests, then adding horizontal scaling (via more web workers on Heroku) is probably an appropriate measure. If, however, the queue is low, yet New Relic reports high request queuing, what you're actually seeing is request latency, and you should examine your `before_filter`s, and either scope them to only those methods that absolutely need them, or work on optimizing the code those filters are executing.

I hope this helps anyone coming to this thread in the future!