# Reducing End User Latency in Herokuapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This question is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256053/scaling-dynos-with-heroku) about scaling in heroku. What I've noticed is that when I use my app it doesn't feel quite so smooth - I've used plugins like YSlow that consistently tell me that the majority of time is being spent on the server side in generating the HTML. New Relic seems to show that my app is spending a lot of time in Request Queuing as shown here:

[image: NewRelicGraph1]

and here:

[image: NewRelicGraph2]

However I also have this bit of information showing me:

[image: NewRelicGraph3]

That seems like a really, really big discrepancy between a 10.7 ms processing time on the server vs 1.3 sec response time that the user is experiencing. What does this mean? What is the best way to reduce the latency for the user? (Again I'm a complete newbie and all help is much appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

You should **change to using unicorn**.  This will only work on the Cedar stack!  It will give you more dyno essentially without buying anymore.

### Quick Synopsis on how:

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'unicorn'
```

Create Rails.root/config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 4 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
timeout 30  # restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds
```

Create Rails.root/Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Commit and push it out to heroku and then **you need to tune it** (experment with the worker_process number).  There is a memory limit per dyno.  If you have too many workers and hit that limit then the dyno will slow down to a crawl.

Reference this article here for more detail: http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/01-more-concurrency-on-a-single-heroku-dyno-with-the-new-celadon-cedar-stack/